# Limit of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}.$$ Now I am aware that clearly $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \tan^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{4},$$ but I do not know what to do if each sum is already sent to infinity. Im taking a limit of limits. I suppose I could rewrite my limit as $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}?$$ But I am unaware if this is helpful at all. Any hints would be appreciated. Obviously, Wolfram calculates this as $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I am unaware of the steps and logic to get there.

Comment: Compare the sum with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac n {n^{2}+x^{2}} dx$

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2+a^2}=-\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{\pi}{2a}\text{coth}(\pi a)$$ If you replace $a$ with $n$, multiply through by $n$, then take a limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ you'll get your sum

Comment: @MatthewPilling Never heard of it. Crazy helpful here though, but then my question would be how do I show this identity?

Comment: I remember seeing sums like this in complex analysis. Look here: https://blog.zilin.one/2014/12/05/poisson-summation-formula-and-basel-problem/

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can I state that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \int_1^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+x^2}dx?$$

Comment: The command of Mathematica `DiscreteLimit[
 Sum[n/(n^2 + k^2), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers], n -> Infinity]` performs $\frac \pi a$. The intemediate result of  `Sum[n/(n^2 + k^2), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` is $\frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}.$ Note that our sum equals

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}.$$

Now $f$ decreases from $1$ to $0$ on $[0,\infty).$ Thus, for $k=1,2,\dots,$

$$\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}f\le f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n} \le \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}f.$$

Summing on $k$ then gives

$$\int_{1/n}^\infty f(x)\,dx \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}\le \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$

This is true for any $n.$ As $n\to \infty,$ the integral on the left approaches $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$ By the squeeze theorem, the limit of our sum equals the value of this integral, which is $\pi/2.$

Comment: Is there any way you can justify your inequality a bit more? I get that we have a bunch of rectangles of height $f(k/n)$ but why width $1/n$?

Comment: We are taking a uniform infinite partition of $[0,\infty)$ of mesh size $1/n.$ The partition is $\{0,1/n,2/n,3/n,\dots\}.$ This generates subintervals $I_1=[0,1/n],I_2= [1/n,2/n], I_3 = [2/n,3/n],\dots$ We sample the values of $f$ at the right hand end points. It's like a finite partition in Riemann integration, except here it just keeps going. I think that once you see the picture it will ring a loud bell because you've seen it before. In fact I'm pretty sure you've seen this picture when you studied the integral test. It leads to a very simple solution of your problem.

Comment: I think I understand the latter inequality but I am having trouble with the former. $\int_{1/n}^\infty f(x)dx$ is the area under a smooth curve starting at $1/n$ for some $n$. The sum in the middle is a bunch of rectangles the first one being nudged in the corner of the first octant (since the right end point rule). In fact it is clear that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty f(k/n)(1/n) < \int_{1/n}^\infty f(x)dx$ so how is simply adding one rectangle going to reverse the inequality?

Comment: $\int_{1/n}^{2/n}f(x)\,dx \le f(1/n)\cdot(1/n)$ etc.

Comment: Oh wow that is awesome. Thank you so much I’ll pin yours as the answer.

Comment: Is there any chance you can elaborate in your answer like you did here in the comments? :)

Comment: I edited my answer a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Denote $\displaystyle \mathcal{S}(n) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$. We have

\begin{aligned} \mathcal{S}(n) & = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{n}{ n^2+k^2} \\& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{2n }{ n^2+k^2}  \\& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{d}{dn}\log\left(1+\frac{n^2}{k^2}\right) \\& = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dn}  \log \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{k^2}\right) \\& = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dn}  \bigg[\log \pi n\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{k^2}\right)- \log(\pi n)\bigg] \\& = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dn}  \log \pi n \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{k^2}\right)-\frac{1}{2 n}\end{aligned}

Weierstrass factorization for hyperbolic sine is:

$$\sinh \pi z=\pi z \prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$$

Therefore \begin{aligned} \mathcal{S}(n) & = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dn} \log \sinh \pi n -\frac{1}{2 n} \\&= \frac{1}{2}\pi \coth(n \pi)-\frac{1}{2 n } \end{aligned}

And finally taking the limit as $n \to \infty$

\begin{aligned} \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{S}(n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\pi \coth(n \pi)-\frac{1}{2 n }\bigg) \\& = \frac{\pi}{2}.\end{aligned}

Comment: Nice! To exchange derivative and series have you used the fact that $f_k(n)=\log \left(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right) \leq \frac{n^2}{k^2}$ and so $\sum_{k \geq 1} \log \left(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right) \leq \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{n^2}{k^2}=n^2 \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2}$ which implies that $\sum_{k \geq 1} \log \left(1+\frac{n^2}{k^2}\right)$ is uniformly convergent?
However, there is a little typo: there shouldn't be $\pi$ at the denominator of $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n} \log(\pi n)$.

Comment: @ZaWarudo That's correct. Good comment.

Comment: Aww, this would have been my answer! :) Nice one, +1.

Comment: This is so clever. I immediately thought of going $\dfrac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\dfrac 12\bigg(\dfrac{1}{n+k}+\dfrac{1}{n-k}\bigg)$ and compare harmonics, but didn't know how to continue from there.

Comment: That is beautiful! Well done seriously

Answer (score 4):

Let $$f(x):= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2+x^2} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} f\left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} \right) dx$$
From this you can do whatever you like to conclude, maybe using DCT while knowing that $$f\left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} \right) \le f(x) \quad \forall n \quad \text{and } \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx <+\infty$$
for a direct conclusion.

**Edit**:  It's probable that you haven't learnt DCT yet, so here is an alternative

If $0 \le x \le y$, we see that:
$$ 0 \le f(x)-f(y) = \frac{(y-x)(y+x)}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2)} \le \frac{y-x}{1+x^2}=(y-x)f(x)$$
Thus for all $x>0$
$$0 \le f(x)- f\left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} \right) \le \left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} -x\right)f(x) \le \frac{1}{n}f(x)  $$
So
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx \ge \int_{0}^{\infty} f\left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} \right)dx \ge (1-\frac{1}{n})\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx $$
Hence forth the conclusion

Comment: I think I did learn DCT in part three of real analysis but I certainly didn’t naturally think to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any chance your willing to show a little more detail on your statement: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2+x^2} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} f\left( \frac{ \lceil nx \rceil }{n} \right) dx$$?

Answer (score 2):

*Another solution.*

$$\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{n}{(k+in)(k-in)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition and summing
$$S_m=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{i}{2}  (\psi(m+i n+1)-\psi (m-i n+1)+\psi (1-i n)-\psi (1+i n))$$
$$\psi (1-i n)-\psi (1+i n)=i \left(\frac{1}{n}-\pi  \coth (\pi  n)\right)$$
$$\psi(m+i n+1)-\psi (m-i n+1)=H_{m+i n}-H_{m-i n}$$
Using the asymptotic of generalized harmonic numbers
$$H_{m+i n}-H_{m-i n}=\frac{2 i n}{m}-\frac{i n}{m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$ Combining all the above
$$S_m=\frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}-\frac{n}{m}+\frac{n}{2 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} S_m=\frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}=\frac{\pi}{2}   \coth (\pi  n)-\frac{1}{2 n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}=\frac \pi 2$$