# $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification

$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

I don't know if it works.

$$
\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy\le\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{x}{x^2+n^2}dy\le\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy
$$

$$
\arctan\frac{n+1}{x}-\arctan\frac{n}{x}\le \frac{x}{x^2+n^2} \le \arctan\frac{n}{x}-\arctan\frac{n-1}{x}
$$

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+n^2} \le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info:  "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have *specific* concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough.

Comment: The previous sentence "does this answer your question" has been automatically generated from a remark of mine saying that this question has been posted several times. But your treatment is original and I congratulate you for finding it. A little remark : the LHS $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x}$ can be written plainly $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

Your work is good.

If you enjoy generalized hermonic numbers, you could also write
$$\frac x{n^2+x^2}=\frac i 2\left(\frac 1{n+ix}-\frac 1{n-ix}  \right)$$ and use
$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {n+a}=H_{p+a}-H_a$$ to make
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac x{n^2+x^2}=\frac i 2\left(H_{p+i x}-H_{p-i x}+H_{-i x}-H_{i x}\right)$$ and use
$$H_{-i x}-H_{i x}=\frac{i}{x}-i \pi  \coth (\pi  x)$$

Then, using twice the asymptotics of harmonic numbers to end with
$$S_p=\frac{\pi  x \coth (\pi  x)-1}{2 x}-\frac{x}{p}+\frac{x}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ and obtain the exact value of the sum when $p\to \infty$.

Comment: This looks quite similar to your answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4155616/42969

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your method is good. You could add some explanation and fill in some steps for completeness.